# Div background-image have x Scroll that i need to remove

Tags: css

I have a div that should have a background-image. The image resolution is high, I need it to take the width/height of the screen size viewport. Scrolling up and down is OK.

The issue is that i am having scroll right/left, i need it removed so that the image fills the whole screen without any x scroll. I put `overflow-x:hidden;` but the scroll remains. Even `overflow:hidden;` didn't do the trick.

```
#bgImg{

background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("images/header.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
/* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
height: 100vh;
max-width: 100vw;
overflow-x:hidden;
/* padding-bottom: 30px; */
}
```

Comment: hi, so have you tried, `max-width: 100%;` ? i think it might be something else triggering this like `body` - `margin` or `padding`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove margin/padding from `body` element and apply the overflow property on **parent container** and not the element with the background (if needed) :

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked now, as you said i applied overflow:hidden on parent element.

Answer (score 0):

It works good for me, but try to add margin 0 and padding 0 to your body tag.

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```